# Trying on ajax jquery if there is no text before the semi-colon want to remove that semicolon

Tags: jquery, ajax

I had tried AJAX jQuery and get the output as response data

```
;first comment;second comment;;;third comment
```

My expected output is this:

```
first comment
second comment
third comment
```

I had used this method to display the text before the semicolon(;) on the next line, but now I am getting the space before the empty value.

```
comments = comments.replace(/;/g, '<br>');
```

I want to remove the empty space which doesn't have text. Please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: maybe try `comments = comments.replace(/;+/g, '<br>');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp) to resolve your problem:

so here the solution is to use `/;+/g`    (one or more ;) and eliminate the first

```
comments = comments.replace(/^;+/, '');    
comments = comments.replace(/;+/g, '<br>');
```

i think you could write on one line:

```
comments = comments.replace(/^;+/, '').replace(/;+/g, '<br>');
```

Comment: its working but want to remove the first semi-colon also. It doesn't remove the first semi-colon if it doesn't have text before it

;first comment;second comment;;;third comment